# In both cases i am passing error as an argument in next()

Tags: node.js, nestjs, middleware

Even in OK case should i pass next after validating the error: instanceof Error??
Can someone suggest me a best practice example.

```
export class AuthMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
      constructor(private readonly jwtServ: JwtService) {}
    
      async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
        try {
          const headers = req.headers;
          const authorization = headers['authorization'];
          if (!authorization) {
            throw new HttpException('Token is missing', HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
          }
          const token = authorization.split(' ')[1];
          const verifyToken = await this.jwtServ
            .verifyAsync(token)
            .catch((error) => {
              return error;
            });
          if (verifyToken instanceof Error) {
            throw new HttpException('Token has expired', HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
          } 
            console.log("-OK--",verifyToken);
            next();
    
        } catch (err) {
            
          next(err);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with nest.js, but I wouldn't recommend calling the `next` function with an error. This obviously depends on your use case so you should evaluate the context in this regard. As you're doing so, ask yourself the following question, "If a user's request is unauthorized, should I let that request proceed to the endpoint's business logic by calling `next`?" Generally, this answer is no. Instead of calling `next`, you should send back a response to the user notifying them of an unauthorized request.